# set-header for HAProxy responses

Tags: haproxy

New in version 1.5 is the `http-response add-header` directive. As written in the [documentation](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-http-response) -- this can be used in `frontend`, `backend` and `listen`.

What I was trying to within a `frontend` section:

```
use_backend some_backend                if some_condition
http-response add-header Vary Origin    if some_condition
```

But this has no effect. The same line placed in the `backend` section works perfectly fine.
Can someone please help me understand, what I am missing here? I don't understand, why this does not work in the `frontend` section.

My guess would be that within the `fronted` there is no response yet and so the directive fails. I tried using it before and after die `use_backend` directive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running haproxy in foreground (`haproxy -d -V -f haproxy.cfg`) with your sample displayed the following warning:

```
acl 'some_condition' will never match because it only involves keywords that are incompatible with 'frontend http-response header rule'
```

Fiddling with my config, I found that this warning is displayed when using this ACL:

```
acl some_condition req.hdr(Content-Type) -i application/json
```

But not when using this ACL:

```
acl some_condition res.hdr(Content-Type) -i application/json
```

The difference being `res` vs. `req`, so checking response headers instead of request headers. This leads me to believe that a `http-response header` rule in a `frontend` is incapable of inspecting `request` headers.

I don't know if this is intended functionality by HAProxy, but it certainly hasn't been clearly documented.